# Why does LD keep outputting "no version information available"

Tags: libraries, dynamic-linking, elf

On every loading of a lib, I get the error:

> no version information available

This lib has been compiled on another PC (ubuntu 10.04) than the one running it (mandriva 2010.2).

```
$ ldd /usr/local/gnu-eabi-4.5.2/i686-pc-linux-gnu/arm-eabi/lib/libbfd-2.21.so
/usr/local/gnu-eabi-4.5.2/i686-pc-linux-gnu/arm-eabi/lib/libbfd-2.21.so: /lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /usr/local/gnu-eabi-4.5.2/i686-pc-linux-gnu/arm-eabi/lib/libbfd-2.21.so)
 linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xffffe000)
 libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0xb77a7000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/i686/libc.so.6 (0xb7655000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb787a000)
```

Edit: the workaround didn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it doesn't.  It appears to mean that the version of libz you linked against when you compiled your program was built with different tools than the version on the madriva system you're using.  The mandriva copy is missing symbol version info which was present in the copy of the libz library your program originally linked against.  This has to do with differences int he respective build environments, not with versions of the libz library itself.

I suspect you'll continue to get the message until you supply a copy of libz that was built with the same toolset as your binary, i.e., a toolset that inserts symbol versions into the library.  Or build your binary with tools similar to those used when libz was compiled on your mandriva system, so no symbol version references are present in the binary.

See:
http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/dynamic-linking/versioned-symbols
http://www.linux-kongress.org/1997/youngdale.html
http://www.usenix.org/publications/library/proceedings/als00/2000papers/papers/full_papers/browndavid/browndavid_html/

I don't know of any tool that would let you modify the binary compiled on the other system to delete the symbol version references you don't want, and leave all others, if any.

Answer (score 3):

That error, "no version information available", means that the version of libz that you linked against when you compiled the library is newer than the version on the mandrivia system you're using.